# Trying to understand the multipart response error "TypeError: Could not parse content as FormData."

Tags: javascript, python, sockets, http, multipart

I have a simple python server that is sending a multipart response to a javascript client, but I get this error `TypeError: Could not parse content as FormData.`

python server

```
import time
import socket
import socketserver
import ssl
import numpy as np
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image

transfer_bytes = BytesIO()


s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
## the reusaddr part means you don't have to wait to restart
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)

s.bind(("localhost",58886))
s.listen(1)
def handle_request(conn):
    print("handling!!")
    response_header = f"""
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Type:multipart/form-data;boundary=xxx  

--xxx
Content-Type: text/plain ;
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="first"

hello world
--xxx
Content-Type: text/plain ;
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="second"

end
--xxx--
    """.strip()
    ## prepare the multipart response

    conn.send(f"{response_header}".encode())
    

while True:
    print("waiting for next request")
    conn,addr = s.accept()
    #conn, addr = ssock.accept()
    handle_request(conn)
    conn.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
    conn.close()
    print("fulfilled request")
    time.sleep(1)
```

javascript client

```
window.onload = async ()=> {
  fetch("http://localhost:58886").then(res=>res.formData()).then(t=> console.log(t)).catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

In the network console on firefox I see that the client recognizes the type as multipart, but for some reason the error still happens.
[image]
[image]

similar questions that aren't exactly the same: [fetch response on client with form-data from server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63603550/fetch-response-on-client-with-form-data-from-server), [Constructing multipart response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21258772/constructing-multipart-response)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with the response

- The line ending should be `\r\n` not `\n`. This is true both for the header as the multipart boundaries and MIME headers in the body. While the browser seems to accept `\n` for the header (even though this is not standard compliant) it is less forgiving for the multipart MIME body.
- The end of the multipart MIME body is `--boundary--\r\n`, not `--boundary`, i.e. the line ending is essential.

This fixes these problems:

```
response_header = str.replace(response_header, "\n", "\r\n") + "\r\n"
```

Comment: That did the trick, thank you for catching my non standard issue!